# Do you need the “why” in “That's the reason why”?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, redundancy, reason-why

I often hear people say things like “That's the reason why I....”

As far as I know, “That's the reason I...” would still be grammatically correct, but I can't find anything stating one way or the other.

Can someone please tell me whether I'm right or wrong?

Answer (score 20):

Yes, that perception is correct.

The reason (why) that perception is correct is that *why* is a rather special relative pronoun.
Indeed, it's a pronoun that can only refer to one word: *reason*.
Try it with anything else and you get garbage:

- *the **reason** why he did it*
- **the cause why he did it*
- **the intention why he did it*
- **the effect why he did it*
- **the thing why he did it*
  (ungrammatical phrases and sentences are marked with an asterisk)

and these are nouns that **could** make sense with a *Why* relative pronoun;
try it, if you dare, with nouns that couldn't, like *rock, salamander,* or *durability*.

Relative *why* can be freely substituted with *that*, like any restrictive relative marker.
I.e, substituting *that* for *why* in the sentences above produces exactly the same pattern of grammaticality and ungrammaticality:

- *the reason that he did it*
- **the cause that he did it*
- **the intention that he did it*
- **the effect that he did it*
- **the thing that he did it*

More important, *why* refers to an adverbial clause or phrase of some sort in the relative clause -- certainly not a noun phrase -- and therefore it can't possibly be the subject of the clause. This is important because relative pronouns that **are** the subject of their relative clause (like *the man **who/that** came to dinner*) cannot be deleted. But adverbial *wh*-words -- like *why, where, when,* and sometimes *how* -- can't ever fall into that category.

This means *why* -- or *that* -- can be freely deleted after *reason*. I.e, deleting *why* in the sentences above also produces exactly the same pattern of grammaticality and ungrammaticality.

It's not a matter of redundancy; all pronouns are redundant, after all.
It's just that *why* is very limited in its distribution.

Not quite as limited as *how*, however.
*How* can't be used at all as a relative pronoun;
one may use *that*, or nothing at all, but
*how* (which refers to *way*) is ungrammatical as a relative marker.

- *the **way** that he did it*
- *the **way** he did it*
- **the way how he did it*

Comment: Good explanation of why it's optional in this case, although I'm not convinced that _reason_ is the only reasonable antecedent of _why._ For example, _the explanation why_ is a common usage, and I don't think you can freely substitute _that_ in that case either. (Perhaps it's already a contraction of _the explanation of why_?)

Comment: I would insert _for_ in _the explanation (for) why `S`_.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: In "an explanation why [...]", the *why*-clause is an interrogative content clause, just as in "to wonder/explain/ask/examine/know/etc. how/why/whether/etc. [...]"; that's definitely distinct from the relative clause found in "the reason why [...]".

Comment: An NP Complement embedded question... Yes, that works, for derived [picture nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299) like _explanation_, provided _explain_ can take an embedded question complement; and it can: _He explained [why they had to fingerprint me]_.

Comment: Note that neither "why" nor "that" are pronouns here.

Answer (score 11):

*Why* and *the reason* are redundant when used together. From [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/why):

> **why** : for what cause, **reason,** or purpose <why did you do it?>

Therefore, these all mean the same thing:

> That's why I. . . .
> That's the reason I. . . .
> That's the reason why I. . . .

While many people prefer to avoid redundancy in writing ([“Omit needless words”](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk5.html)), a little redundancy is often helpful in speech to improve flow and to compensate for the vagaries of hearing and attention span.

Comment: +1 for the redundancy bit. I dislike redundancy as a programmer as try to avoid it all the time, but your explanation allowed me to better realize why redundancy can be good in the real world.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, it's a good idea to wait about a day before accepting an answer, so as not to discourage other people who might have even better answers. (And John Lawler's answer is arguably better than mine.)

Comment: I see. I'll be sure to keep that in mind for future questions. I like your answer simply because it's very "to-the-point", but his is more accurate and informational. While I like both answers, his is probably a better fit now that I think about it. I'll unaccept this and see if anybody else has any additional input before choosing a correct answer.