# Using "since" instead of "because"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, conjunctions

I want to use the word since as because, but I don't know if I can add the word 'then' after it. For example, is the sentence 'since we have A and B, then there is no need for you to get C' correct? Is the word redundant in this case?

And I would like to say 'since A, and B, blablabla.. In this case A, and B are two reasons, should I add then before blablabla to make it more readable? or is this wrong

Comment: Using "then" in these cases is fine. It may be unnecessary (optional), but that doesn't make it incorrect. It's a stylistic choice to use the "then."

Comment: @Nonnal: I disagree. Take a cutdown version of OP's example: *Since A is true, then B is false*, for which the "natural;" order is *B is false, since A is true* (primary statement followed by "parenthetical" additional text). There is no place to include ***then*** in the more straightforward version, *because it should never have been there anyway*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OP gave two examples: (1) "Since we have A and B, [then] there is..." and (2) "Since A, and B, [then] blah blah." The question is, would it be wrong to include "then" in either of these sentences? If you can form a sentence that conforms to (1) or (2) *and* where "since" means "because" *and* where it would be *incorrect* to use "then," then I will acknowledge the error. But, with respect, I don't see how your example sentences fit into the OP's patterns.

Comment: The discretionary _then_ is available for precisely the cases where the `blablabla` goes on so long that the _since_ is no longer within memory range of the conclusion clause. Think of it as a long-distance repeater.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think that your comment applies very well in the case of a protracted "B" clause. "Since A, and [extremely long B], *then* blah blah..." By the time I got to the end of B, it might lose my literary way without the "then."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it wrong for a then clause to follow a since clause?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196941/is-it-wrong-for-a-then-clause-to-follow-a-since-clause)

Comment: @Nonnal that is exactly my situation here. I am writing solutions to mathematics where I need to use conjunctions such as 'since', 'because', and 'as' a lot. In many cases since A, and B are very long; B can be 2 about two lines; my gut tells me if i don't add 'then' to the sentence, the reader would get lost; however, I don't know if adding 'then' is grammatically correct.

Comment: As noted in my comment above and in the linked question that FumbleFingers found, you are fine to use "then" after "since".