# Preposition placement

Tags: syntactic-analysis

1 . . . the the amount of debt for which he was personally responsible.
2 . . . the the amount of debt which he was personally responsible for.

Which of these two forms is preferred for the placement of "for" and why?

Comment: See "[Pied-Piping](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/196947/15299)".

Comment: Try "the amount he owed."

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people try to proscribe (proscribe effectively means forbid) placing prepositions at the end of a sentence.  In actual fact, either of your phrases are fine and you can pick which one sounds best to you, or in your situation.  I would typically feel that it sounds better with the preposition mid sentence, but that's opinion and is unrequired.

The proscription apparently originated from the fact it was a lexical rule in latin.
http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/Ending-a-Sentence-with-a-Preposition.html

In short, a preposition is definitely a sentence you can end a sentence with.