# Is it correct to say "why you pick us" in a sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english

As titled,

Actually, we always use this sentence in a way like:

> this is the reason why you pick us

rather than in a question sentence, but what I am wondering is whether it's correct to use a sentence like the above one in American or British English? Or we must use the complete sentence like

> why do you pick us?

Comment: "Why do you pick us?" is a question. "This is the reason why you pick us" is a statement.

Comment: So, can we say "why you pick us?”?

Comment: In your usage, being selected is a common ocurrence. Someone picks you *more than once*, for example "the job is always dirty, this is the reason why you pick us." Otherwise it would be "this is the reason why you **picked** us."

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't think the phrase was meant as a question in itself, and edited the title to suit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Explain the reason why"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180124/explain-the-reason-why) or [have some reason you or have some reason why you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37639/have-some-reason-you-or-have-some-reason-why-you)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a direct question (such as *Why do you pick us?*) we invert the subject and the auxiliary. *Do* is needed if there is no other auxiliary.

In an indirect or embedded question, which is not a sentence but functions as the subject or object of another verb, we do not invert the subject (and so we do not need the auxiliary *do*):  *This is the reason **why you pick us**.*

Comment: For me, the ‘why’ is a little awkward in there. It’s colloquial but if I were writing formally I’d drop it to get: *“This is the reason you picked us.”*

Comment: Indeed: my father used to fulminate against the redundancy in _the reason why_. Nevertheless it is  comon.