# Is ‘the reason why’ somehow objectionable?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style, logic

It has just come to my attention that some consider ‘the reason why’
ungrammatical or otherwise unfortunate.  David Crystal mentions it in
his introduction to Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage, and
this Oxford dictionary

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reason

says that

> Many people object to the construction the reason why …, on the
>   grounds that the subordinate clause should express a statement, using
>   a that-clause, not imply a question with a why-clause: the reason
>   (that) I decided not to phone rather than the reason why I decided not
>   to phone. The reason why has been called a redundancy to be avoided,
>   but it is a mild one, and idiomatic.

As far as I can see, these ‘grounds’ are a misunderstanding.  ‘Why’ does
not ‘imply a question’ any more than ‘where’ in ‘the place where he was
born’.  It seems perfectly reasonable to me to say

> the reason for which

which is the same as

> the reason wherefore

which is the same, I would think, as

> the reason why

So what is the problem with ‘the reason why’?  I can see neither illogic
nor redundancy in the construction.  It is, of course, possible and
often preferable simply to say ‘the reason he ..’ and ‘the place he ..’,
but surely not always, and the objection seems to be stronger than that.
Besides, I would rather say these are cases of omitting the relative
adverb than call the full formulations redundant.  Is the objection
simply -- as it appears to be -- based on a misunderstanding?

Comment: An expression that some [careful speakers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/is-it-correct-to-say-the-reason-is-because/492941?noredirect=1#comment1189809_492941) consider redundant is not the same as saying it is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that is why I added ‘or otherwise unfortunate’.  What
interests me is the reason why careful speakers avoid this
construction (if that is indeed the case).

Comment: "Reason why is not only not ungrammatical or harmlessly redundant, but it’s a legitimately correct and fully grammatical construction. Just because there are other options doesn’t mean one is right and the rest are wrong." - blog [here](http://www.arrantpedantry.com/2013/05/08/the-reason-why-this-is-correct/)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I think this is right, but I will not click on a link to a blog that uses the "just because .. doesn't mean .." construction.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. _I cannot tell you the reason why she got angry_ is perfectly grammatical. Here, "why" functions as an adjunct of reason.

Comment: [“Have some reason you” or “Have some reason why you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37639/have-some-reason-you-or-have-some-reason-why-you) and  [Do you need the “why” in “That's the reason why”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119877/do-you-need-the-why-in-thats-the-reason-why)

Comment: "The reason why I left the firm was the pay" vs "The reason I left the firm was the pay" they mean the same thing. As to BillJ's example, I prefer *I cannot tell you why she got angry* Why would you add "reason" there?

Comment: The syntactic difference I mentioned is this: in _I cannot tell you the reason [why she got angry]_ the bracketed element is a relative clause. But in _I cannot tell you [why she got angry]_ it's an interrogative clause (embedded question).

Comment: You say some consider it ungrammatical, but who exactly, and what reason do they put forward? AFAIC it just means *for which* when the antecedent is a reason.

Comment: @Minty, sources added.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, the shorter option is often better but surely not always.

Comment: The _reason_ someone does x is, in the estimation of the speaker, _why_ someone does x, so one or the other, not both. I rank the construction on the same level as _the fact that_: never necessary in writing. It can be a handy redundancy is spoken language however. But such concerns are stylistic, not grammatical.

Comment: @KarlG, are you sayng (that) it is good style always to express oneself as concisely as grammatically possible?

Comment: @Toothrot: Bless your heart for not splitting an infinitive. If I had wanted to make a general statement about style, I would have, but in general, concise wins over verbose.

Comment: This is English!  Someone will always find something to object to!