# "Hope" versus "I hope"

Tags: subjects, ellipses, sentence-starts, pronoun-dropping, subject-drop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there omission of subject in sentences like “Thought you'd never ask.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-there-omission-of-subject-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask)

Is it correct to use hope without subject? I have seen may times something like:

> Hope you feel better soon

instead of

> I hope you feel better soon

Is this grammatically correct? Can this be done with other verbs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a feature of language known as ellipsis and is indeed found with other verbs. It is frequently used in speech, but it is not appropriate in formal writing.

Comment: Though, many would use it in day to day semi-formal kind of writing. Agree that it should be avoided in formal writing.