# Omitting "thou" after "hast" or "art" in questions (as in "Hast seen the White Whale?")

Tags: early-modern-english, thou-thee-thy, antiquated

My understanding is that in standard modern English, an explicit grammatical subject is required in all sentences other than imperatives.

However, I've come across across a few examples where the subject pronoun thou is omitted in questions.

Basically my question is: what's the deal with this? Did this used to be standard usage? or is it a nonstandard or dialectal (but still common) usage? or just a quirk of the author or their characters? Is it specific to thou or also seen with other pronouns? Does it only occur in questions? When and why did it arise and when and why did it disappear?

In [Moby Dick](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2701/pg2701-images.html), whenever the Pequod meets another whale ship, Ahab obsessively asks about the white whale. There are a few different phrasings of the question:

- Have ye seen the White Whale? (asked once)
- Hast thou seen the White Whale? (asked once)
- Have you seen the White Whale? (asked once)
- Hast seen the White Whale? (asked five times)

Of course it is the last form (missing the subject pronoun thou) that interests me.

I also came across this in the novel [Moonfleet](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/10743/pg10743.html) (written in 1898, set in 1757 in England):

- "Art sure the well is clean, and that no deadly gases lurk below?"
- "Art sure that thou canst do it, lad?"

Comment: Dropping the subject (["conversational deletion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language) or whatever you'd like to call it) occurs often in contemporary English, too. For example, when someone makes a suggestion I often reply, "Sounds good!"

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, certainly. But I can't imagine anyone saying "Have seen the white whale?" no matter how casual or conversational they may be. That's the type of dropping you expect to see in Spanish, but never in English.

Comment: Yet, "Seen the white whale?" works well. Also, sailors, crazed Ahab included, are renowned for potty mouths and not textbook English.

Comment: @WillLevine Yes, the situations in which dropping subjects is acceptable have certainly changed over the centuries. I was responding mostly to your first sentence, to note that it's fairly common in current English (though perhaps of a different "type" than Ahab's).

Comment: See also [Shakespere](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/101117/1696). (Possible dupe?)

Comment: It's also worth noting that "you" was often used as the plural: "hast thou" (you, the individual I am directly addressing), vs. "have you" (all of you, the group to whom i speak). In truth, I sometimes wish we'd retained the distinction in the language.

Comment: "Hast" unambiguously implies the subject "thou", while "Have" could imply "I", "you" (singular or plural), "we", or "they". I think it's one thing to drop an implied subject, and quite another to elide the verb altogether.

Comment: @WillLevine "...I can't imagine anyone saying 'Have seen the white whale?'" Have you or any of your friends actually said: "BTW, have you seen any white whales lately"? I assume that you aren't in the habit of looking for white whales, any more than I am. Ahab, OTOH, was obsessed with it.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Now I'm tempted to call anyone who drops the subject in a sentence a "potty mouth"... ;-)

Comment: Vaguely related https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58285/is-it-acceptable-to-begin-a-declarative-sentence-with-am

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In [E. A. Abbott's *A Shakespearean Grammar*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.03.0080%3Asection%3D4%3Asubsection%3D6%3Aparagraph%3D241) you will find his entry:

> **Omission of Thou**. (See also 399, 402.) *After a verb ending with the second person singular inflection, the **thou** is sometimes omitted in questions*, as:
> “Didst not mark that?” (Othello, ii. 1. 260.)

In *[A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UtAQDPiwQh8C&pg=PT250&lpg=PT250&dq=%22omission%20of%20thou%22&source=bl&ots=hTSUSAM1rd&sig=ACfU3U3kvPC53OJz0QIIXK6VujDPkhQnrQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNtdbaicL_AhVPecAKHaZoByE4ChDoAXoECBwQAw)* (Otto Jespersen, 2013), Volume 3, it is explained that:

> The frequent omission of ***thou*** in questions (in EIE and
> later ***in archaic style or dialect***) as in
>
> > Art mad? = Art thou mad?
>
> was explained 1.6.36 **from the purely phonetic dropping of the
> weak vowel, after *th* had been assimilated to the preceding *t*: art /ou > art-te, arte > art**, etc.
>
> Examples:
>
> > - Gammer 104 Art deffe.. why canst not heares [ = hear us]
> > - 122 Canst not learn to-night, man? Seest not what is here?
> > - Marl J 1930 Wilt drinke?
> > - 1956 ***hast been in Malta long?***
> > - 1958 Dost not know a Iew?
> > - Sh Gent III. 1.390 Why didst not tell me sooner?
> > - Lr IV. 1.29 Fellow, where goest?
> > - Cy V.5.110 Know'st him thou look'st on? speak! Wilt haue him liue?... Wherefore ey'st him so?
> > - Byron 572 Art sure of that?
> > - Lamb R 11 Dost hear, girl? Why don't you answer?
> > - GE A 2 dost think thee'st finished?
> > - Bennett C 2.44 Who'st been running after?

[The introduction to a 2003 edition of *The Reformation*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Reformation/kDfTP3X3S78C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22omission%20of%20thou%22%20the%20restoration%20arrowsmith&pg=PA61&printsec=frontcover) (a play written by Joseph Arrowsmith in 1673) sheds some light on the contexts in which the *ellipsis of thou* can be used and on the connotations it can convey:

> The use of ***thou*** required verbal forms ending in ***-st*** (e.g., comest or com t) or ***-rt*** (art, wert). *Although the presence of the subject has always been obligatory in English sentences since the early modern period*, the distinctiveness of these endings could at times lead a writer to ***dispense with the pronoun, especially in interrogative sentences*** in which the pronoun should have followed the verb (see Barber 200). In *The Restoration*, this kind of ellipsis had already become *archaic*, but in Arrowsmith’s play it appears several times, in conversations in which a character displays ***an extreme degree of familiarity***: most instances belong to speeches by Lysander and Juliana in which the speaker expresses his or her affection or concern for the person addressed (e.g., in combination with terms of endearment, as in Juliana’s
>
> > “Poor innocent, do’st think that love’s the only cause?” before Lelia, 1.2.21;
>
> or
>
> > “Ar’t’ come, dearest?” before Lysander, 3.3.18).
>
> Some of these, however, are ***feigned expressions of affection***, or appear in the ***context of mock-heroic discourse***, to the extent that it is difficult to ascertain whether the ellipsis of *thou* should ultimately be regarded as a ***device with mocking overtones***.

Comment: You have a particularly charming typo, "Joseph Aerosmith" (auto-correct run amok?)

Comment: :)) Will edit... I felt funny typing it but I still did it!

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! So basically we ended up with questions like 'Hast seen the white whale?', but not 'Have seen the white whale?', because there's a phonetic similarity between the end of hast and the beginning of thou, but no such similarity between have/you. (I will accept the answer after waiting a day or so for other answers.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Now I want to know more about this "Joseph Aerosmith".  Hast the album?

Comment: "Ar’t’ come" isn't an omission of "thou" as such, but merely a contraction, as evidenced by the apostrophe placement.  It expands to "**Ar**t **t**hou come".  This doesn't apply to "do'st" however.  But it's easy to see how spoken word and less careful writing will eventually lead to dropping the apostrophes entirely.

Comment: I love this answer because it's an authoritative enumeration of what is essentially (a) artistic license, (b) dialect or cultural habit or (c) laziness. I love humanity. We want to explain *everything.* Maybe someday and anthropologist can explain to me how that behavior evolved.

Answer (score 4):

To give a broader perspective: *hast* unambiguously indicates that the subject is the second place singular pronoun. This phenomenon of dropping the subject pronoun is quite ubiquitous in Spanish, Italian, Russian, Arabic, and other [*pro-drop languages*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language). It is impossible in modern English, because it has (almost) lost its inflections, and dropping the subject can make a sentence ambiguous. But it was certainly possible when these inflections still existed.

Comment: Although a bit buried, this is mentioned in one of the quotes in fev's answer: "the distinctiveness of these endings could at times lead a writer to dispense with the pronoun". Still, +1 for pointing out that this is a common practice in many languages, so might have happened in English regardless of phonetic factors, had we not lost most of our inflections.