# What is the correct term for the style of writing used on resumes that does not have a subject?

Tags: american-english

On resumes, I frequently see a style of writing like the following:

> Acme Corp -- Contraption Designer
>
> Designed systems for catching road runners. Coordinated with clients for delivery in remote locations. Collected statistics on system efficacy.

The writing here does not actually include a subject, instead the "I" is implied. This is similar to an imperative sentence but instead in the past tense.

I found [one source](https://kellydonovan.com/introduction-resume-speak/) that called this "first person implied", but the source does not seem to be very reputable.

Is there a term for this sort of writing? Are there any style guides for it?

Comment: @KannE "first person implied" (in quotes) only has ~2000 results on Google, so I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linguistic sources call it a *null subject*, *subject pronoun drop*, or *diary drop*:

- [Subject pronoun drop in informal English](https://awweir.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/weir-ug-diss.pdf)
- [Diary Null Subjects: A relevance theory perspective](https://eprints.kingston.ac.uk/id/eprint/25728/1/Scott-K-25728.pdf)
- [Adult Null Subjects in the non-pro-drop Languages](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245217665_Adult_Null_Subjects_in_the_non-pro-drop_Languages_Two_Diary_Dialects)

As the first source explains, “diary drop” is a more specific term used for this phenomenon in written language: “subject pronouns can frequently be dropped in certain registers of written English, such as diaries but also including text messages, emails, and other forms of informal communication”.

Comment: Ah thank you. That also leads to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80730/is-there-a-name-for-the-practice-of-dropping-pronouns-in-written-speech/80785#80785 which is a related question.