# Pronoun “you” can be omitted as subject in imperative form, what other pronouns can be omitted, when and why?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, conversational-deletion

The pronoun *you* can be omited as a general rule, but sometimes I’ve seen sentences that should have used *I* or *it* as the subject but it was omitted.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. Have any examples? A specific sentence where "you" can be omitted would be very useful, for us to know what you're asking.

Comment: "you" can be omitted when the verb is in the imperative. When else?

Comment: @PeterShor For instance "go home" vs "I go gome", the first sentence refers to YOU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Standard English, the subject can be omitted only in an imperative sentence:

> - Go to the store.

Colloquially, you can sometimes sneak by with an implied subject if there’s enough context:

> - Got something to say?
> - Went home sick — fell asleep immediately.
> - Am not!

Comment: "Got something to say?" is referring to whom?

Comment: @rraallvv It’s not referring to anybody; it’s addressing someone.  It’s in the second person.

Comment: Nice examples. Gratifyingly sneaky.

Answer (score 5):

Leaving off the first word, or words, in a sentence is a common conversational strategy in English, explained [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299). It's called "***Conversational Deletion***" in the trade.

The deleted material often is, but need not be, a subject pronoun; **any** word or phrase that's predictable can be deleted, followed by the next predictable chunk, etc, until new information is reached. This is not random, but is governed by the usual syntactic rules, as explained in the dissertation mentioned in the link above.