# Is there a term that describes leaving out the implied subject of a question?

Tags: single-word-requests, subjects, conversational-deletion

For example, "**Not going?** Be sure to cancel at least 24 hours in advance." has an implied "Are you…" in front. Is there a term for this concept?

Is it proper grammar (or at least accepted in business communication)? I feel I've seen this structure use a *lot*.

**Update**

Is this just an example of [conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/182312)? I'm guessing "conversational" means it would be generally okay for marketing and user interfaces but not for a memo to the CEO (or other more formal documents).

Comment: A very common expression can't be said to be ungrammatical. Of course you could say it is informal, or inappropriate in formal writing.

Comment: @MετάEd Good point. I edited the question to clarify the "is it proper?" question

Comment: This is answered at [Pronoun “you” can be omitted as subject in imperative form, what other pronouns can be omitted, when and why?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95808/pronoun-you-can-be-omitted-as-subject-in-imperative-form-what-other-pronouns), but someone will probably claim that doesn't make it a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I went ahead and flagged it, although *technically* I was asking what the concept is called ;-) Seems to be "Conversational Deletion", since that was mentioned in answers in both questions (the one I linked & the one you linked). Whatever helps future Internetters find the answer!

Comment: A search for 'omit subject' gets you into the various duplicates.

Comment: at the risk of wandering into "conversation" territory… "omit subject" will also return questions regarding a broader set: Conjunction Reduction, for example. I posted the question, because I was having trouble figuring out what happening in this specific case