# meaning and usage of "mind you"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I often come across this expression and according to dictionaries I've looked up, it can be used in several ways such as to:

1. introduce something that should be taken into consideration
2. add something to what you have just said, especially something that makes it less strong
3. draw attention to an important fact that is important to a statement

but how do you use the expression in a sentence/conversation?

Comment: The pragmatic use of _, mind you,_ (always a parenthetical phrase, normally set off with commas) is very similar to the pragmatic use  of _[not that](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/110102/15299)_. I.e, it's used to mention and dispense with important topics that are not under discussion but must be kept in mind. Normally it's a sign that the topic being mentioned won't occur again in the discussion, because all presuppose it. Thus it can also be used surreptitiously to commit listeners to presuppositions.

Comment: If people are to know what’s on your mind you will need to supply examples of what sort of thing you’re thinking of. I don’t mind you updating your question to include them. Mind you, these should come from [actual books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mind%20you%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) if possible.

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with that, mind you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think of "mind you" as meaning something very like "on the other hand". It introduces a new idea related to the main topic, often a contradiction or counter-example.

*Teenagers today are terribly rude. Mind you, I was probably just as bad when I was that age.*

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be a little bit more appropriate if considered as "in addition".
E.g.:

> She is quite fancy, but mind you, she has got a lot of money to afford it.