# Are these questions grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, questions, sentence-starts

I have seen questions like

- "He went through all that just to go to Columbia?"
  or
- "That's the Ferrari?"

and I would like to know if they are grammatically correct.
Can you use questions like that in regular speech?
Can you even start a question with "you" or "that"?

Comment: *"You want what?", "That is whose?"* :)

Comment: **You** should definitely visit our [sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), ELL, which is a good site for basic English questions. **That** site might be more helpful to you than EL&U. Thanks.

Comment: There exists no word that cannot occur in the first position of an English utterance, even the postpositives: ***“Galore* sure is a weird word in English, isn’t it?”**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These questions are grammatically correct. In written English, there is nothing wrong with indicating an interrogative solely by putting a question mark at the end. In spoken English, intonation is used for this purpose. There is no requirement that the interrogative mood be clearly expressed in the words used.

You can certainly start a question with "you" or "that". The easiest way is by eliding a word like "do", "did", "are", "is", or "can":

Omitting "do": *You really expect to make out in that sardine can?*
Omitting "did/does": *That help?*
Omitting "is": *That what you were looking for?*
Omitting "are": *You sure?*

Comment: Thanks for answer (really well explained) so the questions "It is car?" and "Is it car?" are both gramatically correct?

Comment: @user82115 Sure. Imagine if I said, "Can you guess what my favorite means of transportation is?", you could respond with either of those. ("It is car?" is awkward, but not incorrect. "It's car?" would be a typical response in idiomatic spoken English.)

Comment: These are all examples of [Conversational Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), btw.

Comment: I feel like there is something horribly wrong with omitting "a" or "by" in "It('/i)s car?" It works either by omitting everything and just saying the noun ("Car?", "Bike?", "Train?") or keeping the connector between the (copula?) "is" and the noun. It might be tense agreement, because you could say "It's cars?" which is fine, but the singular "car" and lack of "a" sticks out. I don't feel that way about other examples of conversational deletion in John's link.

Comment: I agree. Whatever else you think about "It's car", it's *definitely* not idiomatic spoken English.

Answer (score 0):

Spoken language and literature alike have a license with grammar.

Sentence structures can be manipulated, words and phrases elided, all in an attempt to convey the right emotion.

*That's the Ferrari?* means quite a different thing from the "grammatically correct" *Is that a Ferrari?*

The latter is essentially a request for information: Yes, or No.

The former, loaded, possibly implies "You call *that* a Ferrari?" or even, "I don't call that sort of thing a Ferrari" depending on the contextual emotion.

Similarly, it is very difficult to create the kind of "effect" that the sentence

> He went through all that just to go to Columbia?

evokes in the listener. Note that this sentence is **not** a question. It's an exclamation, like *Really?*, implying something like

> "I don't see how going through all that is justified just to go to Columbia, period."