# "Can" or "could" in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: can-could

> Could / Can Happiness bring pain?

The above sentence is not meant to mean the past time. "Could", and not "can", is used for past. So, "can" is preferable in the sentence?

On the other hand, the sentence is meant to ask whether there are possible conditions under which happiness bring pain. Or, does it ever happen that happiness brings pain. So, since it is about future possibility, isn't "could" a better choice?

Comment: What is the context? If it *is* describing something in the past, then you've answered your own question. If you *aren't*, then either word is possible. But, again, more context would determine that.

Comment: @JasonBassford it is mentioned in the question that the sentence is not about the past time.

Answer (score 1):

*Can* and *could* are both modal auxiliaries and they both refer to [possibility and probability.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182264/15299)
So do the other modal auxiliaries.

**All** of the following questions (which are all grammatical) ask
"whether there are possible conditions under which happiness brings pain".
The first verb in each case is a modal auxiliary verb. None of them refer to the past.

- ***Can*** happiness bring pain?
- ***Could*** happiness bring pain?
- ***Might*** happiness bring pain?
- ***Must*** happiness bring pain?
- ***Should*** happiness bring pain?
- ***Will*** happiness bring pain?
- ***Would*** happiness bring pain?

Forget about "past tense" with modals. Modal auxiliaries are uninflected and have no tense at all.
*Could* only refers to past time in specialized constructions, which are rare.
It does not usually refer to the past.

The same applies to the other "past" modals: *would, might, should, must*.
They refer much more often to the future, in fact.

Comment: Though, is there a difference in the meaning of "can happiness ..." and "could happiness ..."?

Comment: Yes, but that's to be expected. Modals don't mean "the same thing" -- they refer to different types of possibility, probability, and certainty, mostly in idioms. But possibility, probability, and certainty, as determined by personal judgement, is what they all refer to.

Answer (score 1):

*Can* and *could* are both fine here, though I would recommend adding *ever* to clarify the intended meaning (unless other context already makes that clear):

- "Can happiness ever bring pain?"
- "Could happiness ever bring pain?"

The difference between the two is that *can* seems to be asking about whether it ever *really* happens, whereas *could* seems to be asking about whether it could even *hypothetically* happen. (Neither of these is strict, however; we can say things like, on the one hand, "Is there any possible world where happiness can ever bring pain?", and, on the other hand, "Do you think that, in the average person's life, happiness could ever bring pain?")

> […] the sentence is meant to ask whether there are possible conditions under which happiness bring pain. Or, does it ever happen that happiness brings pain.

But those aren't the same! For the former, I'd recommend *could*; for the latter, I'd recommend *can* (or *does*).