# Asking questions without "do" in them

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, questions

In school, we learned that in interrogative statements to use do (e.g. *Do you want to go there?*).

I'm wondering if there are any cases when *do* is not required.

For example, I'm thinking if this is this correct: *Want to learn to code? I may help you.*—meaning that if the asked person wants to learn programming, it could be possible that I'm available to teach her/him programming.

So, what is the difference between *Want to learn to code?*/*Want to code?* and *Do you want to code?*

Also, how can this be this question changed to have the same meaning, to be correct but still friendly and informal (e.g. it should be something that can be posted on Twitter)?

Comment: @Yay Thanks! But how can I make my question friendlier (the last paragraph of my question).

Comment: I don't think you can, unless you identify a specific concern not adressed in previous posts. I'm not sure your last paragraph is enough to make this different from other questions. However, although your question may be closed as a duplicate, it may also get some good answers until then—or maybe, it's not closed at all. Who knows.

Comment: You certainly don't have to use "do".  You can ask, eg, "Would you like to go there?"  Or, "Would you like to learn to code?"

Comment: "One of us should code, and the other test.  Want to code?"

Answer (score 1):

No real difference between ***Do you want to learn to code?*** and ***Want to code?*** They're saying the same thing; in the second example, the ***Do you*** is implied.

It's like saying ***Nice day*** instead of ***It's a nice day.*** It's the same thing really—just a matter of formality versus informality.

As far as making it a friendlier interrogative, one of the comments suggests ***Would you like to learn to code?*** That's a great fix and works well. So does something like ***Looking to learn how to code?*** or ***Interested in coding?***

Comment: Actually, there's a big difference between "Do you want to learn to code?" and "Want to code?"  It's the case of "Do you want to learn to code?" and "Want to learn to code?" where the assumed "Do you" is the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two constructions is formality:

> Want to code? (informal)
>
> Do you want to code? (formal)

Informal language often sounds friendlier, and formal language often sounds more precise. So it depends who the intended audience is, and how much emotion versus accuracy you want to convey.

Answer (score -3):

Want to learn to code? means *if you wanted to learn the process of coding.*

Want to code? *is bad, drop it.*
and Do you want to code? means, *if you wish to do coding by yourself without any supervision or training.*
Hope, you get it.