# Why is it "Anybody have...?" instead of "Anybody has...?" here?

Tags: grammatical-number

See the text below:

> Let's hear it for Apple's very first touchscreen device, the Newton
>   MessagePad. Anybody have one of these?

Notice the last sentence in the above snippet. Shouldn't it read "Anybody has one of these?" instead? **Anybody** is singular so using **have** there seems a tad out of place. Is it a colloquialism? Or just incorrect grammar?

To give you a bit of context, the text is from a MacLife magazine article about the history of Apple devices, recently [shared on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/maclife/photos/a.194462203528.155206.20637528528/10152880018343529/?type=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a colloquial, informal way of saying "Does anyone have...?"

Comment: Yes. _Anybody has one of these?_ is something I can't imagine a native English speaker saying or writing.

Comment: But you'd say, "IF anybody has one of these..."

Comment: The *Anybody ha(x) ...?* form uses the singular; as does "Ha(x) anybody ...?" whereas "Does anybody ha(x) ...?" form uses the regular plural. Other ways are ungrammatical, which needs to stated, I suppose.

Comment: -1 for not citing a reliable source. It's essentially an opinion.

Comment: +1 for being correct anyway. If @Rick is a native English speaker, he knows about [Conversational Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), whether he's familiar with the term or not. And native speaker intuition is a reliable source; certainly better than non-native intuition.