# Ok, if we omit "It" in "It sounds fine", then it should be written as "Sounds fine" or "Sound fine"?

Tags: word-usage

Here is a conversation in an English material.

```
A: You should take part in  a music club
B: Sounds fine
```

I am not sure "*Sounds fine*" is a correct writing way. I feel that it should be "*Sound fine*"

So "*Sounds fine*" or "*Sound fine*", which one is correct?

Comment: When you omit a subject, you do it because everybody around you can understand what is omitted based on the context. "Go home" is directed to someone in front of you and that's why *you* can be omitted before "go". The subject is "taking part in a music club" in the context and everybody knows it is singular.

Comment: Find out more about the phenomenon [in this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A: You should join  a music club
>   B: Sounds fine.

That is an abbreviation. In full we have:

A: You should join a music club.
B: That sounds fine.

or

A: You should join a music club.
B: That idea sounds fine.

Whichever way you look at it, the verb should be 3rd person singular.