# Is this type of ellipsis natural?

Tags: grammar, writing-style

As far as I know, using ellipsis in the second part of the sentence is very common. However, using it in the first part of the sentence looks unusual, at least to me. Is it grammatically correct to use ellipsis in the first part of the following sentence?
"*His first was a failure*, but this second book is a total success."

Comment: Sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @WS2 So this type of ellipsis is natural among native speakers.

Comment: @midomido In your first language, is ellipsis grammatical and are there strict rules about where it can occur in a sentence?

Comment: I'm not so sure it's OK with _this second book_; I read it as _his second book_ at first, and that's OK. But changing the possessor to a demonstrative screws up the structure required for what I spose is reverse conjunction-reduction. Rather like the way gapping works in Japanese and other SOV languages.

Comment: @M...d l don't think this type of ellipsis is used in my first language.

Comment: This seems to be an example of _cataphora_.

Comment: My impression is that the ellipsis is okay because the meaning is so similar to that of a construction in which the ellipsis would be grammatical, *viz.* "Though his first was a failure, this second book is a total success."  I dub this *parasitic ellipsis*.

Answer (score 3):

There is no rule that states ellipsis has to come at any point in a sentence, or that a parallel structure must be involved.

> Looking good, John! Getting more exercise?

Here we've elided a few words:

> [You are] looking good, John! [Have you been] getting more exercise?

For your own example, I think it's not only fine and valid, it's also better because it's fresher and not necessarily expected and therefore **not boring**. What you're doing is holding off until the second clause to let the reader (or listener) know the *real* subject of the sentence. That piques curiosity because the subject can't be dismissed until it's at least brought up, and it isn't brought up until later, by which time there has been a slight but real anticipatory build-up.

Indeed, manipulating tension is a key element of style.

Comment: Thank you, Robusto. I have thought that making ellipsis is limited to later parts of the sentences. So it is stylistically appropriate.

Comment: This is a particular kind of ellipsis, called "[Conversational Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299)". It follows rules, like all deletions. "Ellipsis" is a very vague term, and just means that something is missing that might or should be there; it says nothing about what's missing or how it happened, or what rule it followed. Or how we can tell it's sposta be there, for that matter.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Looking good, John! Getting more exercise?

Comment: @Robusto: As a matter of fact, I just got back from the Y.  You?  :-)

Comment: @JohnLawler: I did my daily 16.25 mile route on the bike. So yeah.

Comment: @John Lawler Thanks. But, what's wrong with the demonstrative "this" ?

Comment: I don't really know. I'm still trying to figure out the original question; it seems to be substitution for an identical NP (his book) is OK, but not for just a noun (book). Not enough data to hypothesize further.