# Is "Tomorrow good?" a complete sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, zero-copula, conversational-deletion

Is this a complete sentence:

> Tomorrow good?

As I understand it, first you change the interrogatory to declarative so the question becomes whether **Tomorrow (is) good** is a sentence.

Comment: You might benefit from looking up 'sentence fragments' which some confusingly term 'minor sentences', and 'crots', here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

It's acceptable in dialogue. It's short for "Is tomorrow good?"

Answer (score 0):

Although it can be understood by inflection, '[is] tomorrow good' is ambiguous with 'tomorrow [is] good', so 'tomorrow good' is not grammatical.

Comment: Agreed but this has a question mark so you know the inflection

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, it's not a complete sentence. It's an incomplete sentence, like *Get out of here!*
Both of these lack their first word. In one the missing first word is the preposed auxiliary *is*,
and in the other the missing first word is the subject pronoun *you*.

This is all part of a general and very common phenomenon in spoken but not in formal written English 
called ***[Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299)***. No need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very interesting link. I didn't know that an imperative like Go! was considered an incomplete sentence. I thought that the understood subject and all the understood parts make it complete (i.e., I order you to go!)

Comment: But I'm not a grammarian. I write and these distinctions usually don't concern me as I do know that the piece's formality dictates what's proper to some degree. To me, just as a layman, a sentence is complete if there is no ambiguity in the subject, verb and object. (Note: this statement does not mean logically that if a sentence is ambiguous it's not complete.) So Tomorrow good? is, by my definition, complete if it's texted to one person and the context makes clear what "good" means. When I wrote that in a text, a grammarian commented on my use of sentence fragments so that got me thinking...