# Is it ok to use just "Careful!" instead of ”Be careful!” preceded by “be”?

Tags: grammaticality, ellipses, exclamations, sentence-fragments, conversational-deletion

Is it “correct” if I say *Careful!* here without *be* in front of it?

- Careful! There is a car coming!
- Careful! Just one step back and you will fall off the cliff.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/197194 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93947 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95849 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/305413 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/361016

Comment: Rules of grammar are not very useful for giving sudden warnings. If there's only time for one word, don't make it an auxiliary verb.