# “It’s very rare that…” or “It’s very rarely that…”

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I’ve read and heard **“It’s very rarely that opportunity knocks twice”** and I wonder whether it shouldn’t be **“rare”** instead.  Since “it” (in this particular case)  is a nominative pronoun introducing the noun clause, I would expect an adjective instead of an adverb.  e.g. it’s very **interesting** that/it’s very **unusual** that/it’s most **unlikely** that/etc.

For example, I wouldn’t say “**It’s very rarely for a person to live to be a hundred**.”  To be honest, If I had to say something like that, I would probably say “It’s **unusual** for a person to live to be a hundred”.   Assuming, however, that I had to use either “rare” or “rarely”, I think I would spontaneously choose “It’s very rare…”

In a sentence like “It’s very ______ that opportunity knocks twice”, should we say “It’s very rare” or “It’s very rarely”?  The same question goes for similar sentences like the other example.

**EDIT** - I expect an answer explaining why one form is correct and the other isn't (or that maybe both are correct) and also expect comments on the two sentences I've posted.

Comment: Let's see what it' gives with other words. "It's often that .." and "it's common that ..." are both acceptable. You can either use an adverb (*often*) or an adjective(*common*). Same case for "rare" and "rarely".

Comment: Not all that common, but [*It's obviously that X*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it%27s+obviously+that+the%22) seems fine to me in contexts where it's a shortened version of something like *It's obviously **the case** that X [is true]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your *it’s obviously that X* is not grammatical in the most  common case, although there are perfectly legitimate ways to complete *X* in which it would nevertheless now pass muster. Muse upon this: there’s a vast difference between *the leaves of Lórien falling not idly* and *the hammers of Moria falling not idle*, and once you can explain why *it is not idly* lends itself only to the first and *it is not idle* lends itself only to the second, you will have come upon the distinguishing structural issue that underlies this astute and intriguing question.

Comment: @tchrist♦: I never intended to suggest it's not an astute and intriguing question - simply that this *kind* of "confusion" isn't all that uncommon. I'm intrigued by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+very+rare+that%2Cis+very+rarely+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20very%20rare%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20very%20rarely%20that%3B%2Cc0), which seems to suggest that significant preference for the explicitly adjectival form in OP's context only really arose in the past half-century.

Comment: @tchrist 'Fall idle' is getting close to a multi-word verb, along with 'fall silent'. Dummy it here, I would say, goes beyond the superbly poetic to the grotesque. Didn't Tolkien use 'Not idly do the leaves of Lórien fall' even with the simplex verb? ... ... ... Ah, 'lightly'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, he wrote [*Not idle do the leaves of Lórien fall*](https://goo.gl/9BmPIR). The alternation we find in literature between adverbs derived from adjectives on the one hand and prepositional phrases used adverbially on the other is interesting: *noisily, faintly, swiftly, idly, quickly* compared with *by chance, in vain, with all possible speed, at length, like a steep stair, like a green sea, at last, by night*. I do feel that *it is [ADJ]* is more common (nowadays?) than *it is [ADV]*, but that may or may not be because of the “what does *it* mean here?” question.

Comment: @tchrist The 'lightly' I found is a tribute, I suppose, but the original is 'idly'. It's the link verb + resultative vs verb + adverb scenario, but I don't think a dummy _it_ rewrite can be automatically considered acceptable.

Comment: OK four legged horse-man thing. I've done my worst!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually there isn't a preference for one or the other in this context, because in actual fact they are two completely different contexts which just happen to look similar. (See my short answer below - or the long one if the fancy takes you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Short answer:**

The Original Poster's sentence using the adverb *rarely* is an *it*-cleft construction. The clause following the adverb is a relative clause which has gaps in it. In contrast, the Original Poster's sentence using the adjective *rare* is an extraposition. The clause following this adjective is not a relative clause. It is a normal subordinate finite clause with no gaps in—often called a *content clause*. Although they look very similar, the two types of sentence are very different.

---

### Full answer:

> 1. It’s very rare that opportunity knocks twice.
> 2. It’s very rare for a person to live to be a hundred.
> 3. It's very rarely that opportunity knocks twice.

OK, so there are two particular types of sentence in English with *it* at the beginning that look very similar, and can occasionally even look identical. As it happens, sentences (1) and (3) here are mutually exclusive in the sense that they cannot be alternative versions of the same type of sentence. Rather, they exemplify two very different and interesting constructions which happen to look very similar.

### ***It*-clefts**

4. Bob gave you the elephant.
5. It was Bob who gave you the elephant.
6. It was Bob that gave you the elephant.
7. ?It was Bob gave you the elephant.

Sentence (4) is a canonical sentence. It follows our everyday, mundane expectations of a normal English sentence. Sentences (5) and (6) convey the same information, but this information is arranged differently and the sentences carry a different sort of emphasis or focus. They seem to place a lot of emphasis on the word *Bob*. We can say that the noun phrase *Bob* has been ***foregrounded***.  The rest of the information in the sentence is usually said to have been ***backgrounded*** and appears in a relative clause at the end of the sentence.

Sentences like these are called clefts because the information in the canonical version of the sentence has been split or 'clefted' into two different constituents. One bit of it gets foregrounded and the other bit backgrounded and put in a relative clause. They are ***it***-clefts, of course because the Subject position in these sentences has been filled by a meaningless dummy subject, the word *it*.

The foregrounded part of an *it*-cleft is the semantic antecedent for the relative clause. So in (5) and (6) the word *Bob* is the antecedent for the relative clause *who/that gave you the elephant*. But unlike normal *restrictive* (also called *integrated*) relative clauses, the antecedent and relative clause in an *it*-cleft do not form a single constituent. So, for example, in (5), there is no single noun phrase "[Bob who gave you the elephant]". Rather we have the noun phrase *Bob* appearing as the Complement of the verb *BE* and another separate constituent *who gave you the elephant* occurring outside of the nucleus of the clause.

These relative clauses are nonetheless more like restrictive relative clauses than non-restrictive ones. For example, these relative clauses can, of course, be introduced by the word *that*, as in example (6) above, whereas non-restrictive relative clauses cannot. Notice as well that when the verb in the relative clause has its own subject, it can occur bare without the words *that*, *who* or *which*. In the example above the verb *gave* does not have its own subject and so example (7) with a bare relative clause is degraded and may be ungrammatical for some speakers. Compare that with examples (8-11) below.

8. You gave the mongoose to Sheila.
9. It was Sheila [who you gave the mongoose to].
10. It was Sheila [that you gave the mongoose to].
11. It was Sheila [you gave the mongoose to].

Here we see that example (11) with a bare relative clause is perfectly acceptable because the verb *gave* has its own subject, the word *you*.

Lastly, notice that because the bracketed strings are relative clauses, they have gaps in which are semantically co-indexed with the antecedent. So we can model (9) above like this:

- It was Sheila<sub>i</sub> [that you gave the mongoose to ____<sub>i</sub> ].
- It was Sheila [that you gave the mongoose to <s>Sheila</s> ].

One thing that does separate out these types of relative clauses from integrated relative clauses, however, is that they can take a wider range of antecedents than normal relative clauses. So we can have adverbs or adverb phrases, for example, as the foregrounded antecedents in *it*-clefts:

- It was only recently<sub>i</sub> [that I noticed _____<sub>i</sub> how much money had gone missing].
- It was only recently [that I noticed <s>only recently</s>  how much money had gone missing].

In the sentences above, we see the adverb phrase *only recently*  appearing as the antecedent for the relative clause.

### **Extrapositions**

In English we don't really like to have clauses functioning as the Subjects of sentences. The main reason for this seems to be that they are very difficult to process:

12. That you went and asked my ex-girlfriend out without asking me first made me mad.
13. For her to accept your offer so enthusiastically seemed poor taste .
14. To do that kind of thing to your best friend can be very bad for your health.
15. For people who engage in such activities to be subject to freak kicking-accidents as they leave the building is not unknown.

The sentences above are all grammatical, but we don't like to use sentences like these ones very much because the clauses functioning as Subjects make them clunky and hard going. It is much more normal for us to shunt those clauses down to the end of the sentence where they appear as separate Complements of the verb and then to stick a dummy pronoun, the word *it* in Subject position:

16. It made me mad [that you went and asked my ex-girlfriend out without asking me first].
17. It seemed poor taste [for her to accept your offer so enthusiastically].
18. It can be very bad for your health [to do that kind of thing to your best friend].
19. It is not unknown [for people who engage in such activities to be subject to freak kicking-accidents as they leave the building].

We often see sentences like this with an adjective functioning as a Predicative Complement of the verb *BE*:

- To feed the lions is **dangerous**.
- It is **dangerous** [to feed the lions].

Notice that we cannot use adverbs in this way. Adverbs cannot normally function as Predicative Complements of the verb *BE* and almost never when the verb *BE* is used in its ascriptive sense like this:

- *To feed the lions is dangerously.
- *It is dangerously to feed the lions.

### **The Original Poster's examples:**

> 1. It’s very rare that opportunity knocks twice.
> 2. It’s very rare for a person to live to be a hundred.
> 3. It's very rarely that opportunity knocks twice.

Sentences (1) and (2) are extrapositions. We can give clunky but canonical versions of these sentences as follows:

1. [That opportunity knocks twice] is very rare.
2. [For a person to live to a hundred] is very rare.

Notice that we cannot replace the adjective *rare* with the adverb *rarely* here, because *rarely* cannot freely function as a Predicative Complement:

1.#  *That opportunity knocks twice is very rarely. (ungrammatical)

2.#  *For a person to live to a hundred is very rarely. (ungrammatical)

Sentence (3), however, is not an extraposition. It would be ungrammatical if it was, as is shown in (1#) above. Rather it is an *it*-cleft. The canonical version of *this* sentence is:

3.# Opportunity knocks twice very rarely.

In example (3) the adverb *rarely* has been foregrounded, and the rest of the information occurs in a relative clause at the end. The relative clause has a gap in it which is co-indexed with the adverb phrase *very rarely*:

- It is very rarely<sub>i</sub> [that opportunity knocks twice ____<sub>i</sub>].
- It is very rarely [that opportunity knocks twice <s>very rarely</s>].

Notice that we cannot use the adjective *rare* in sentence 3#:

- *Opportunity knocks twice very rare. (ungrammatical)

So although the Original Poster's sentences with *rare* and *rarely* seem very similar, they are, in fact, completely different!

Comment: I gotta go to work now but I will read it later.  Looks like a thesis, though.

Comment: I don't know where one draws the line between flagging "suspect" constructions with a preceding asterisk, or 1 or 2 question marks, but I have no problem with things like [*It was you did that!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+was+you+did+that%22). But if it was up to me, I'd have put *at most* one question mark against your example #7. I can see that lots of people might object, but lots of people just *say* things like that without knowing or caring about "formal grammar".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I definitely think that that's marginal in relaxed speech or certain dialects. I wont' forget it was you said that to me. But, as in that last sentence, I think it requires a new intonational phrase. It can't be said in the same pitch contour. I haven't proof-read this yet, as I'm meant to be at the pub with my Ss right now (but have popped back to school to pick up my bag).

Comment: But if you agree it's "marginal", doesn't that imply you accept that it's at least "credible" to some speakers? I thought the (single / double) question mark meant *only acceptable to (some / a very tiny number of) native speakers,* where the asterisk means *not acceptable to **any** native speakers*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Useful comment. Still pondering ... How did you feel about "I won't forget it was you said that to me" in the comment above?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I checked out your "It was you did that" link but could only find one example there ... I think that single example was a bad attempt to emulate a different labguage variety from the author's.

Comment: @Centaurus Ah, but there's a short answer for you if you've had a long day at work :)

Comment: To a witty pine tree from the southern hemisphere I must say: I've read it all and I'm buying it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Ayup, I think of that line from the end of the original *King Kong*: "It wasn't the airplane. It was beauty killed the beast."

Comment: @Robusto: ['That wasn't me said that, was it?' she breathed.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22that+wasn%27t+me+said+that%22) There comes a point where you have to choose the lesser of two evils - overload the utterance with three ***that's***, or risk the wrath of pedants everywhere. My position is words are cheap, so it doesn't matter if we throw some away.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK, you've convinced me. How'z that?

Comment: And for the record, this does feel similar to [conversational deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask/66994#66994) to me.

Comment: Excellent work. +1

Comment: @lawrence Thanks for that! Have corrected.

Answer (score 6):

The example you give has multiple possible syntactic interpretations, as FumbleFingers alludes to in his comment.

The crux here isn’t so much adjective *rare* vs. adverb *rarely*, but more **what kind of *it* the subject is** and, consequently, what the basic structure of the sentence is. *It* as the subject of a sentence can be either a regular pronoun (in the literal sense, meaning *pro-noun*, i.e., standing in for an actual noun phrase and thus having a particular reference), and functioning as the real, semantic subject of the sentence; or it can be a [dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) that doesn’t have any real referentiality and is only needed for purely syntactic reasons—in this case, there is a semantic subject somewhere else.

1. If we take “it” to be a dummy-*it*, then that logical, semantic subject must be “that opportunity knocks twice”. The sentence is then equivalent to “That opportunity knocks twice is very [rare/rarely]” (this type of replacing a subject with a dummy-*it* and then having the real subject at the end is called [extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition)). In this case the subject is represented twice, as it were: once in purely syntactic terms by the preliminary dummy subject “it”; and again at the end of the clause by the logical and semantic subject “that opportunity knocks twice”. If we collate those two representations into one and just say that the subject is *X*, then the structure of the sentence is underlyingly simply “X is very rare(ly)”, and it’s clear that *very rare(ly)* can only be a [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement). Since adverbs like *rarely* cannot function as subject complements, but adjectives like *rare* can, *very rare* is the only possibility here.
2. If, on the other hand, we take “it” to be a true pronoun, with an implied antecedent not present in the sentence, then we have a wholly different structure: “it” is the actual subject, so “that opportunity knocks twice” cannot be—it must be something else. In a copular clause like this, the only options realistically available are adverbial phrase and subject complement. As stated above, adjectives like *rare* can function as subject complements; so can [noun clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause#Noun_clause) like “that opportunity knocks twice”. But you can’t have two subject complements like that. Luckily, *rarely*, being an adverb, can function as the other option, an adverbial phrase, which solves things: “It” is the subject, “is” is the verb, “very rarely” is an adverbial phrase modifying the verb, and “that opportunity knocks twice” is the subject complement.

With the second way of parsing the sentence, the antecedent to *it* is usually something like “the reason” or “the case” or “the problem”. Alternatively, you can interpret it as being a shortening of “It is rarely [the case/reason/problem/…] that…”, which would be another case of a construction with an extraposed subject, this time equivalent to “The case/reason/problem is very rarely that opportunity knocks twice”.

In the sentence given, you’d need a slightly contrived context for the that interpretation to make much sense semantically—after all, if opportunity knocks twice, that is rarely a problem. With a bit of licence, though, something like the following might work: “I’ve never known much luck. Missed chances pass me by like so many fireflies in the headlights. If ever I end up doing something a second time over, *it’s rarely that opportunity knocks twice*, more often it’s a case of it never raining but pouring.”

But the difficulty of wrangling that interpretation is due to the particular semantics of your sentence. Other examples would work differently. For example, “She’s missed so many classes this term. It’s rarely that she cuts school, it’s just that she can’t get out of bed in the morning and ends up being late.”

(This is all, of course, assuming the traditional role of *rare* as an adjective and *rarely* as an adverb.

I’m sure there are speakers who confuse the two and end up using *rarely* as an adjective—after all, adjectives in *-ly* are not rare (excuse the pun), as your own example “It’s not unlikely that…” exemplifies.

While I have no statistics to back me up here, I would expect that using *rarely* as an intended adjective in construction #1 would be considered ungrammatical by the vast majority of native speakers. Using *rare* as an intended adverb in construction #2 would likely fare slightly better, but would probably still be ungrammatical to most.

In other words, I’d say the assumption that we’re using *rare(ly)* in their traditionally accepted roles is a fair one to make.)

Comment: You’re right that it’s all about what *it* really is. Try these on for size... If he now **speaks strangely**, then it is *strangely* that he now speaks. But if the very fact that he should now happen to speak **is itself strange**, then **it is strange** for him to speak now / strange that he speaks now / strange that he should speak now.

Comment: The related construction 'It happens very rarely that ...' requires the ly-form adverb, and 'It is [very] rare that ...' has surely achieved idiom status.  Possibly 'It is very rarely that ...' is a deleted form of 'It is very rarely the case that ...'.

Comment: @Edwin I don’t think there’s anything need to suppose any deletion, really. Using “it is [adverb] that [clause]” to mean something like “[the thing under discussion] [adverb] comes down to [clause]”: “it’s not that I don’t like him”, “it’s just that it never helps”, “it’s mainly that I don’t have enough space”, “it’s mostly that I don’t feel like it”, etc. _Rarely_ isn’t particularly commonly used like that, but I don’t see any reason why it shouldn’t be. You could of course argue that all these are deletion forms, but I don’t think it’s necessary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Let’s swap *rarely* for a word not derived from a common adjective. [*Seldom well an outlaw ends*](https://goo.gl/9MoIgK) or less prosaïcally *An outlaw seldom ends well* would under this transform become *It is seldom that an outlaw ends well*.

Comment: These things don't pattern well. 'It is very frequently that ...' seems to out-perform 'It is very frequent that ...' even if one tries to filter out the 'The reason is very frequently that' usage.

Comment: If it's a case of subject extraposition, then the content clause "that opportunity knocks twice" is the displaced subject in extraposed position, outside the VP, not the actual subject which can only be dummy "it", whatever the analysis. But dummy "it" is not referential, so the AdjP "very rare that opportunity knocks twice" is not a PC.

Comment: @BillJ I'm not sure I quite understand what (if anything) you're disagreeing with. _It_ is clearly the syntactic subject, with the content clause being a displaced subject. I wouldn't argue that “rare that opportunity knocks twice” is the predicative complement—or indeed a phrase at all, as far as I can grok it. “Rare” itself is the PC. I don't see the relevance of the referentialness of “it”, though; is there a requirement I'm not aware of for subjects to be referential in order to support PCs?

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Comment: @BillJ I'm still not sure what (if anything) you're disagreeing with in my answer. Your answer says the same that mine does, leaving out the alternative (and in this example less likely) interpretation only possible with _rarely_.

Comment: No it doesn't. Compare our answers - the differences are clear

Comment: @BillJ Not to me they're not. Yours says precisely the same as part of mine using slightly different terminology. The only fundamental difference is that you don't comment on the alternative parsing (structurally akin to “It’s often/seldom that opportunity knocks twice”) at all, and that I seem to have skipped the word _very_ by mistake in my answer (which I will rectify in a moment). Apart from that, we both say that it must be _rare_ if it's a case of subject extraposition and give the same underlying structure as evidence.

Comment: I think you went round the houses a bit and didn't mention that it is an extraposition construction, which is the crucial evidence that not only is impersonal "it" the subject, but that only adjectival "very rare" is possible.

Comment: @Bill I didn’t use that term, but “dummy-_it_” and “logical subject” amount to the same thing. I’ve edited in some more detail and a more thorough explanation, including the term ‘extraposition’.

Comment: Couldn't it be an it-cleft?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth " 'It is very frequently that ...' seems to out-perform 'It is very frequent that ...' " <--- Yes, but those two strings are from very different constructions that just happen to look similar, I think. I might be wrong, but see my answer below.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, I'd say it could be an _it_-cleft; but it could also be a straightforward surface-equals-underlying construction, equivalent to (for example), “The issue is very rarely that opportunity never knocks twice”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet My brain has been stretched out of its normal functioning capacity. I think you're right - but I'll have to ponder and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

It can only be "rare". There is no doubt that:

> (1) It is very rare that opportunity knocks twice

is a case of extraposition of a sentential subject and that

> (2) That opportunity knocks twice is very rare

is the corresponding sentence without extraposition. In both cases, "very rare" is subjective predicative complement. From an intuitive semantic point of view, this is quite obvious: what is claimed to be very rare is the possibility that opportunity should knock twice.

Adverbial "rarely" would be impossible as subjective PC in either version; that is particularly clear in the non-extraposed version.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "rarely" can't be placed after "it is" as the focus in the it-cleft construction. Do you mean when people say "Opportunity rarely knocks twice", you can't put "rarely" after "it is" and say "It is rarely that opportunity knocks twice" in the same way you put other adverbs or adjuncts in the focus?

Comment: Any reason why you don't consider this possibility?

Comment: I said "rarely" is not possible in the OP's extrapostion construction or the non-extraposed version of their example.

Comment: Hmm, but couldn't the sentence be an it-cleft?

Comment: @Araucaria No, it's a different construction. The _that_- clause is a declarative content clause here, not a relative clause as found in clefts.

Comment: @BillJ I think that it could be an it-cleft. I think it's ambiguous between the two. "It is [rarely][that I ___ leave home without my phone]."

Comment: @Araucaria I don't follow you. Where's the relative clause? Apart from dummy "it" as subject, I can't see any resemblance at all.

Comment: @BillJ Well that would make [that opportunity _____ knocks twice] a *that* -relative as opposed to a content clause in that reading. Compare "It is not often that you see a giraffe walking down Oxford street in a bikini". It's pretty difficult to construe that as an extraposition, imo [but I'm not sure].

Comment: What would the antecedent of "that" be?

Comment: @BillJ It would be *often*. The range of elements that can be antecedents for relative clauses in *it*-clefts is a bit broader than in other RCs. CamGEL, p. 1419, give the following example [16 (iii)] "*It isn't often they're as late as this*", which looks pretty similar to me. What d'you think?

Comment: Also, notice that in the OP's version with *that*, the adverb "rarely" sounds ok. That's because, imo, it's possible to read the *that*-clause as a relative clause instead of a content clause. Notice though that in the version with a non-finite clause with the subordinator *for*, the adverb *rarely* is uncontroversially ungrammatical. I think that's because, of course, the *for*-infinitival cannot be construed as a relative clause. *Rarely* is of course barred in the expraposition reading because it cannot be a PC. That's my current thinking anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47985/discussion-between-billj-and-araucaria).

Answer (score -1):

It is very rare 
It is rarely 
Very is an adverb and rarely is an adverb so we should avoid using double adverbs together

Comment: Should we avoid using double adverbs in phrases like "I very rarely see her"?