# is it common to use " you done? " instead of " are you done? "

Tags: expressions

http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTY4MiZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTY4MiZlZD0yMDE0LTEyLTE5VDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4

in the above video someone use " you done? " instead of " are you done " is it common in English?

Comment: It's colloquial, but ungrammatical.

Comment: This would be a common query in spoken English.  "Ungrammatical" only if your "standards" don't permit elided verbs.

Comment: In spoken English, the "are" in "Are you done?" is often swallowed so that the question sounds like "Ya done" or "You done", even when the "are" is intended.

Comment: This is actually an example of [Conversational Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), which is completely normal and grammatical in spoken English. It's frowned upon in formal writing, however, unless you're reporting dialog.