# "You mean the guy who sells fruit?" or "Do you mean the guy who sells fruit?"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, ellipses, do

In conversation, which is correct:

> You mean the one with the guy who sells fruit? 
>   or
>   **Do** you mean the one with the guy who sells fruit?

My ESL student has asked me why we don't always include the auxiliary verb, "do," in instances like this. Why is it ok to say "You mean...?" as a question in conversation.

Why don't we need the auxiliary verb before "you"?

Comment: "Ellipsis" we can skip auxiliaries when the meaning is clear.

Comment: ...especially when it is something more dramatic than selling fruit: "You mean this is our last chance?"

Comment: Another case of [*Conversational Deletion*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299).

Comment: This is a better place to look: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask/66994#66994

Comment: We can add question marks to any sentence we want ?