# how to politely and natively reply an email and ask question

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, phrases

I am replying an email which ask me to submit extra documents. But I think I do not need to submit it.

So I want to ask if it is necessary to do it:

> Thanks for your email. But may I confirm with you that **I do need** to
>   submit these documents please? As I have been studying as a PhD
>   student for a year and I'd like to make a transfer application to
>   follow my supervisor who will teach in your University.
>
> Thanks in advance and best regards.

Would you please give me some suggestions to make it more polite and more likely to what a local will say?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

"Thank you for your email. Can I please confirm that in order to make a transfer application I need to submit the following documents? [list]. I have been studying as a PhD student with [professor's name] for a year, and I'd like to follow my supervisor who will soon be teaching at your University. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Kind regards [your name here]"

If submitting a hardcopy add a handwritten signature as well as the typed name.

Comment: I would replace "Can I" with "Could you" or something along those lines (or just leave it off entirely). Technically, *I* can't "confirm" anything because I don't have the answer.

Comment: @aesking, I don't understand your comment. I am not advocating the use of "can"; I am suggesting that the subject of the sentence should be *you*, not *I*.

Comment: @ScottM Oh, I see! Well what I meant was “Can/could I please confirm *with you* that...” would work as equally well as “Can/could you please confirm that...”. The former is tautological but may be more polite. I got confused over the can vs could thing because you showed preference for could in your comment.

Comment: @aesking I think this is one of those case of slight dialectic differences in acceptable syntax where I'm from "can I confirm...", or "can I get..." in the first instance, is an accepted form for asking a person for information but it may not be strictly speaking grammatically correct.

Comment: @Ash Yes, personally when I upvoted your answer I didn't see anything wrong with it because I'm also susceptible to the same dialect where the syntax "Can I confirm" or "can I..." etc. is acceptable. I wouldn't say it is **grammatically incorrect**; but rather informal. The phenomenon is referred to as [conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask) or [subject omission](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148269/omission-of-the-subject-for-friendliness/169801#169801).

Comment: @aesking I'd consider it formal enough to put in an official written request as well as using it in verbal conversation, I'm a kiwi though, we can have extremely low standards for formality sometimes.

Comment: @Ash another thing is, I don't know in "Can **I** please confirm with **you**" if *you* is the subject or object // English doesn't really distinguish between the cases; but syntactically, it's in the object position // So it may be *object omission* or something along those lines! I'm from Northern England and you can't help it if it's part of your dialect :P

Comment: @aesking Pass, I only speak the language I'm out of my depth when I get too far into syntactic analysis.