# can we omit the subject while talking?

Tags: speech, subjects

ı have read a book and heard of it a lot.someone is talking and says"could not sleep last night" or "just preparing" sentences like that can we always do this or just only while speaking

Comment: Not so much the subject as anything predictable at the beginning of an utterance. The phenomenon is called [***Conversational Deletion***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but it's casual in the example you cited.  Imperative sentences usually have an implied subject, but answers to questions could as well.  If someone asked where I was born, I wouldn't say or write "I was born in America."  I would respond simply "America."  It's arguable about whether this is a true sentence, but I would side on it being a sentence with an implied subject and verb.