# Can not understand the meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning

I'm watching BBC's *Sherlock*. In one of the episodes, he is saying:

> ”Don't want to be doing roast pork, not if you're slicing up cadavers."

but I can't understand what does it mean. Could you rephrase the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

A "cadaver" is a dead body intended for medical dissection.
Pork is said to have many similarities in the way it looks and smells to that of human flesh.

I assume the character is warning how there could be a conflict of the stomach if one works with human flesh and eats pig flesh.

Comment: can you explain, why the structure of the sentence is built in such a way? Why not just say "I see, you don't want to eat a fried pork, because you slice cadavers." ??

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko Oh, you want to know about the lack of a _You_ subject? That's [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299).