# Elision of "it" and "what" at the beginning of sentences

Tags: pronunciation

I am reading *American Accent Training*. I find sometimes either 'it' or 'what' at the beginning is omitted.

e.g.

> It's in the bag. [tsinə bag]
>
> What's in it. (Though labeled [w'ts ..] I only hear [tsini])

I have learned some rules about elision of /t/ and /h/, but I googled and failed to get rules about the elision at the beginning.

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: An unstressed syllable could be reduced or dropped in rapid or careless speech, but that's hardly limited to initial sounds, or to American English. Written forms like *'twas, 'tween, 'twere, and 'twixt* long predate the existence of American English, suggesting an even longer tenure in spoken use.

Comment: "American Accent Training". Really? This is a thing? I do a pretty mean Deputy Dawg and my Muskie is quite good; could I monetise this?

Comment: Well, Ah do declay-uh, Dep'ty Dawg!

Comment: This sounds like a case of [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), which drops dummies, auxiliaries, pronouns, complementizers, prepositions, and other predictable grammatical words at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @John Lawler，I think you give me a clue.