# Colloquially Shortened Sentences

Tags: colloquialisms

Colloquially, people tend to speak in "shorter sentences" and leave out words like *pronouns* and verbs such as *do*, *be* and *have*, especially when it's clear who or what they're talking about. They might also omit whole phrases:

> Do you want me to try getting the shelf off for you? 
>   -------> Want me to try?

Another example:

> Are you sure you've got time? 
>   -------> Sure you got time?

Now, what are the shortened versions of the following sentences?

> Would you like a drink?
>
> Do you have any green tea?

Are they shortened in the same way as the examples below?

> Do you want a drink?
>   -------> Want a drink?
>
> Have you got any green tea? 
>   -------> Got any green tea?

Comment: Like a drink? Have any green tea? Notice: the shortening means dropping the helping verb and pronoun.

Comment: This answer your question? [Why is the subject omitted in sentences like "Thought you'd never ask"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask)

Comment: @JohnLawler No, it doesn't. I've been very specific. I've only asked about "Do you have.." and "Would you like..." which would sound weird if shortened to "like a drink" and "have any g tea"

Comment: "Like a drink?" And In BrE, "Got any green tea?"