# Is "Based on a true story" a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

Is "Based on a true story" a grammatically correct sentence if it was at the end of a paragraph discussing a story? I view this as a proper sentence with an implied subject and as grammatically sound. Is there a good way to explain this if this is correct?

Comment: With an implied subject it's valid.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299) that's been idiomatized in advertising, especially for movies and TV dramas. So it would be short for _(This movie is) based on a true story_. Though what "true story" means, in the context of another story that's only "based on" it, is a good exercise for mental muscles.