# Past tense Implied subject

Tags: terminology, past-tense, imperatives

When describing an action preformed by myself, others, or others and myself, I often leave the subject out of the sentence.

> A: What did you do yesterday?
>
> B: Climbed a mountain.

What is this called? Is it a mood? Is it still technically the imperative or can that only be second person future ?

Comment: An "imperative" is a ***command, order, instruction,*** where the implied subject ***you*** (the addressee) is omitted. So that would be ***[You] Climb a mountain!*** (you can't make an imperative using ***past*** tense).

Comment: Then what do I call this?

Comment: A spoken utterance in a conversational context with an implied subject. [I] Climbed a mountain.

Comment: Terms like "imperative mood" aren't all that useful for describing ***English*** (they're essentially hangovers from terminology relevant to dead languages such as ancient Latin and Greek, that often simply don't relate well to modern English). Note that "imperative" refers to *the verb form itself* (which is largely irrelevant to English, since it's just the same as the infinitive) - it's just that we typically use it as an example of a construction where we routinely omit the contextually-implied subject.

Comment: This is not a mood. Nor is it imperative; no orders were given. This is what is called [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), and it happens all the time in normal speech. All those little markers at the beginning of an utterance are predictable if it's a normal utterance, so we just omit them until we get to something new; that's when the talk starts.

Answer (score 0):

As John Lawler pointed out, this is a case of **conversational deletion,** where the predictable (and obvious in context) pronoun "I" has been deleted from the start of B's utterance.

Comment: John clearly links to a duplicate thread.