# 'yet' and tense of the sentence

Tags: tenses, sentence-meaning

"You try breaking that window yet?"

I can't guess the exact tense of this sentence, because of 'yet'.
Is it a question for someone who is trying to break the window or have tried to break it?

Comment: It's a non-standard but fairly common partaphrase of "Have you tried to break that window yet?"

Comment: The past tense _Did_ at the beginning of _Did you try breaking that window yet?_ has been deleted by [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299) because it's predictable from the construction _you try breaking_, which can only occur after inversion and _Do_-support in a question. It has nothing to do with the _yet_, which just helps justify the past tense of the deleted _did_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: But *could* we delete the 'did' if 'yet' wasn't present? It sounds really quite off to me -- "[You] try breaking that window?" doesn't seem to completely convey the meaning of "Did you try breaking that window?". Which I don't find to be the case with "[You] try breaking that window yet?". / (I do have a guess for why one of the two forms, "Try breaking that window?", doesn't seem to convey the intended meaning completely to me: I think it's because "Try breaking that window?" can also be used as a tentative, underconfident suggestion to someone (which the two latter ellipted....

Comment: ... forms, because of the 'yet', cannot), and so its association with the unellipted *question* is weaker than that of the latter ellipted forms.)

Comment: As you point out, the presence of _yet_ changes the context and thus the predictability of various markers.

Comment: @JohnLawler, another thing: Apart from the dissertation reference in the link, do you know of any other good references to study Conversational Deletion, which are more easily available to buy or read online? Thanks!