# Do question tags after dependent clauses form complete sentences?

Tags: question-tags

Most often, it seem question tags are used after independent clauses to seek agreement with the complete idea expressed in said clause.

'He went to the store yesterday, didn't he?'

However, in some forms of media, and in everyday life, sometimes question tags come after clauses that could not stand on their own as a result of dropping the subject of an independent clause, and it creates a sort of inverted question.

'Had fun, did you?' (from: 'You had fun, did you?)

'Think you're so clever, do you?' (from: You think you're so clever, do you?)

'Real proud of that one, aren't you? (from: You're real proud of that, aren't you?)

I'm curious to what extent the above usages are correct, and if there is a specific term / specific rules for these usages.

Thanks in advance (:

Comment: 'Had fun, didn't you!' (note the exclamation mark rather than the question mark as this is an exclamation rather than the solicitation of an answer; cf 'How do you do!') is available, with a different reading (a deleted version of say 'You really had fun, didn't you!') But 'Had fun, did you?' (the question mark here clawing for a response, in attitude if not in words, and showing the raised tone on 'you') is usually the precursor to something like 'And who do you think's going to pay for the damage?'

Comment: tags on their own do not "make a complete sentence". And they are only used in **spoken** language. Also, dependent or independent clauses have nothing to do with them. They refer to an entire utterance. Real speech often truncates things like: You think, You were, etc. Only the main verb and complement are used.

Comment: You appear to have rediscovered [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), which deletes predictable material at the beginning of a sentence, like auxiliary verbs and pronoun subjects, which are also part of tag questions. But those are separate rules. You can do either, neither, or both:  _Went to the store yesterday, didn't you/he/she/they?_ can refer to any subject, but _Go to the store yesterday?_ means _you_ is the subject; *_went_ is impossible because a question would use _do_. And so on. Both rules are complex and they interact a lot.