# Is using "Got" proper in this case?

Tags: have-got

> Got any questions?

Is this a proper quick way to ask someone if they have any questions?  On a website, the pop up to prompt and online chat says "Got any questions?"

Comment: Hello, 472. Someone has to decide what 'proper' means in these cases. Most seasoned Anglophones would just answer the question in informal situations such as with friends, on a chat site. But if this was used instead of say "Do you have any questions?" in formal contexts, some might worry about a certain lack of propriety and/or style.

Comment: I would add to Edwin's response that the circumstance you describe is one where the designers of the website have made a choice to be informal.

Comment: Ever since the popular "Got milk?" advertising campaign, this form of informal question has been common.

Comment: And you could go in the middle and use, “Have you got any questions?”

Comment: A typically shorter version is "Any questions?" Or on a website, "Ask a question."

Answer (score 1):

This is another example of [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), an English syntactic rule that's very common in speech, but fusses some people who wanna have all their auxiliaries lined up in front of them.

> (by the way, academic "formal" situations like lectures and conferences are the most
> informal things you can imagine; everybody's polite but the in-jokes fly)

Basically, CD chews up the beginning of the sentence, starting with the first word, and throws away any predictable pronouns, articles, dummies, auxiliaries, possessives, conditional *if*, plus assorted short grammar chunks. If the first word is deleted, CD looks at the next word; if it, too, is predictable, out it goes.

This is basically the way people ordinarily talk -- lots of shortcuts, very little formal grammar, get to the meaningful parts fast. And this rule results in the change from

- *Have you got any questions?* (normal speech)

to

- *Got any questions?* (normal CD result)

which is what an American speaker would say, at least.

A few other examples, to give you the scope of the rule:

> - (1.16) *Gotta go now.*
> - (1.17) *See you next Tuesday.*
> - (1.18) *Too bad about old Charlie.*
> - (1.19) *No need to get upset about it*.
> - (1.20) *Been in Pennsylvania long?*
> - (1.21) *Ever get a chance to use your Portuguese?*
> - (1.22) *Ever get to Japan, look me up.*
> - (1.23) *Good thing we didn't run into anybody we know.*
> - (1.24) *Last person I expected to meet was John.*
> - (1.25) *Wife wants to go to the mountains this year.*
>   [all from Thrasher 1974 p.5]