# relative clause? syntax unclear

Tags: relative-clauses

the syntax of the following is unclear to me:

- *There was also a donation event, the proceeds to be applied to provide food for the homeless.*

My particular difficulty is with the latter clause, which I believe to be a relative clause.

1. Shouldn't it contain "of which", as in "the proceeds of which to be applied..."?
2. which function has the "to be" in this clause? it seems missing something. For example, can I say: "there is dinner on the table, the dessert to be eaten last"?

Comment: Could you please provide more of the surrounding text

Comment: (2) It wouldn't be ungrammatical, but is so formal that it would be considered faintly ridiculous in everyday speech by native speakers.

Comment: After a charitable event has been mentioned in the conversation, certain things become presupposed; one is the generation of proceeds, which may be mentioned anarthrously. The phrase _proceeds to be shared_ is short for _(of which the) proceeds (are) to be shared_, in telegraphic/headline/advertising style, which tends to take [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299) to the clausal or phrasal level to save words and make slogans.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why did they choose to write this syntactic monstrosity? Answer: **because they learned Latin.** Latin has an equivalent construct (an ablative absolute with a gerundive) that is idiomatic and fairly common. This is *exactly* how you translate such a construction  very literally into English. Some Latin teachers will actually recommend or even require this painfully literal translation, since it demonstrates that you fully understand the syntax of the original Latin.

Comment: (A further note: the "to be ___ed" translation is common for the gerundive because the gerundive is actually a future passive participle and the sense of obligation is only (strongly) implied. "(Is) to be ___ed" is *also* a passive construction where the sense of obligation is implicit, so Latin teachers tend to abuse it when translating gerundives. Combine that with translating ablative absolutes (common in Latin) into nominative absolutes (rare in English), and this is what you get. Ugh.)

Comment: It's an awkward sentence, to be sure. Things have been done to it that should not have been. Yes, it's a reduced relative clause, yes, it's missing _of which_, and yes, it should be a tensed clause, not an infinitive. I think the writer or speaker just wanted to get it out fast and get on with it. This is in the nature of an after-afterthought, and grammar is far less of a consideration than CYA.

Comment: For me, the structure is basically appositional.

Answer (score 1):

That clause is a **nominative absolute** (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute)). The meaning is clear if we rewrite it as a separate sentence:

> There was also a donation event. The proceeds *were* to be applied to provide food for the homeless.

"Is to be" is an idiom used to give commands or describe plans (see [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/be-to-verb-are-to-get)). The latter meaning seems more likely here:

> There was also a donation event. The proceeds *were planned to be* applied to provide food for the homeless.

On its own, the sentence also likely implies that the plan was followed, but that depends on context.

Nominative absolutes are more common in very formal writing. But this one is convoluted by any standard.

Comment: The proceeds were planned to be applied is not semantically valid.

Comment: It sounds valid to me, but "intended" may be a better fit.

Comment: It was planned that the proceeds would be applied. People plan things or things are planned by people. Proceeds can't plan anything.

Comment: "The proceeds planned" would be incorrect. But I wrote "the proceeds *were planned,*" which is passive voice and does not imply that the proceeds were doing the planning.

Comment: This usage is not uncommon--[take this TechCrunch article:](https://techcrunch.com/2014/06/10/augmented-reality-augmentation-blippar-has-bought-layar/#:~:text=From%20what%20we%20understand%2C%20the%20deal%20was%20planned%20to%20be%20announced%20officially%20on%20June%2019.%20) "From what we understand, the deal was planned to be announced officially on June 19."

Comment: Or from [the NYT:](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/12/12/greathomesanddestinations/12break1.html#:~:text=Another%20pool%20is%20planned%20to%20be%20added%20next%20year%2C%20and%20an%20existing%20spa%20and%20a%20fitness%20center%20are%20scheduled%20to%20be%20overhauled%20then%20as%20well.%20)  "Another pool is planned to be added next year."

Comment: If you take the passive sentence "Another pool is planned [by some agent] to be added next year" and make it active, it doesn't fly: [Some agent] plans another pool to be added next year. OR: "The deal was planned [by x} to be announced officially on June 19th",  [X] planned the deal to be announced officially on June 19th. The first doesn't work (but is speech, not writing) and the second changes the meaning.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, it doesn't really make sense if you turn it into the active voice, but it's an idiomatic usage nonetheless. This usage is quite old: [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xHndgBVEYlcC&pg=PA417&dq=%22is+planned+to+be+used%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0) are [two](https://books.google.com/books?id=1kIwUFr4_KYC&pg=PP31&dq=%22is+planned+to+be+used%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifnpuhsJX9AhVKlIkEHZRHDuIQ6AF6BAgNEAM#v=onepage&q=%22is%20planned%20to%20be%20used%22&f=false) examples from 1921.

Comment: It should be possible to turn all passives into actives. If you can't, then, the utterance doesn't work. And just finding examples, doesn't work for me. Cheers.