# Does the phrase "persuaded by the prosecutor's evidence" lack a verb?

Tags: phrases, verbs

I was checking out the definition of a phrase and found a definition which says it doesn't contain a subject/verb and gave the following example:

> Persuaded by the prosecutor's evidence, the jury convicted the defendant of robbery

In which the phrase is the following:

> Persuaded by the prosecutor's evidence

But isn't persuaded a verb?

Comment: Sure, persuaded is a verb. But that phrase does not contain a subject and a verb.

Comment: _Persuaded_ is one form (the past perfect participle) of a verb. Participles are often used as adjectives, though not here.  So it doesn't lack a verb; it **does** lack some auxiliary verbs, though. Here _persuaded_ is the relic of _having been persuaded_; the _by_ phrase indicates that the participle is part of a passive construction, somewhat chewed up by [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299).

Comment: The subordinate adjunct clause has no overt subject, but we understand it as "the jury". So it is a clause with an _understood_ subject and a verb, "persuaded". The verb "persuaded" is untensed, so we have a non-finite clause functioning as an adjunct, more specifically a passive one. Btw, the comma marks the clause as a supplement, a non-integrated adjunct as opposed to a modifying one.

Answer (score 1):

> I was checking out the definition of a phrase and found a definition which says it doesn't contain a subject/verb

That definition is incorrect. [Cambridge defines "phrase" as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/phrase)

> a group of words that is part of, rather than the whole of, a sentence

There are various more precise, technical definitions of the term, but no definition would exclude the participial phrase "persuaded by the prosecutor's evidence" in the sentence you mentioned.