# Is “Wally the walrus to get ‘floating boat’ to stop him sinking boats” grammatically correct? How should this be used then?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, sentence-fragments, headline-english, whiz-deletion

[image: picture of a walrus]

I can't see a verb-part of the sentence here. Is it even a sentence? Some kind of absolute construction? The picture, of course, speaks for itself and the general meaning is clear, but I am still curious.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is standard headlinese. You can look through this site (or various other sources) to find out about that "version" of English. (This site even has a [tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headline-english) for it.) It is not unusual at all.

Comment: It's missing a *from* between *him* and *sinking*.

Comment: @tchrist One could also change "him" to "his" (as unusual as that might sound), although many people would say that it's fine as is. This is the common transformation of a possessive before a gerund into object case.

Comment: Below I provide an argument for why you need to treat "him" as the subject of the gerund, not as an object followed by an omitted "from." On the latter interpretation, the headline would not necessarily entail that the walrus is *already* sinking boats, when in fact the headline clearly does entail as much.

Comment: *from* in "stop him sinking boats" is not needed in the English of the British Isles, where the quote is taken from.

Comment: @AndrewLeach — The absence of *from* doesn't sound odd to my American ears, headlinese or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the subject omitted in sentences like "Thought you'd never ask"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask) See also 'Is article and auxiliary verb omission in modern English an emerging phenomenon?'