# What kind of statements are “the best pie I’ve ever eaten” and “the most beautiful mountain I’ve seen in my life”

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-requests, phrase-usage

My partner always makes statements such as those in heading. They are always sensationalised to create emphasis and drive home his enthusiasm for the subject. For example we were discussing Florence in Italy and he said “probably the most beautiful city I’ve ever seen in my life!”

I’m curious to know if there’s a linguistic explanation for these kinds of declarations.

Comment: In all languages, speakers use shortcuts. Chocolate with hazelnut cream? The best.

Comment: *Best* and *most beautiful* and *greatest* and even the colloquial *best-est* are known as superlative adjectives.

Comment: Predictable, meaningless introductory constructions, like _that is_, [are often deleted by rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), precisely because they are predictable and meaningless.

Comment: Which part of the declaration are you looking to have explained? The exaggeration? The deletion of "that is/was"? The syntax of the phrase?

Comment: It’s often referred to as *hyperbole*.