# Present Simple instead of Present Perfect in colloquial speech

Tags: present-tense, present-perfect-vs-simple-past, do-support, conversational-deletion

I was recently watching " The Last of Us" series and was pretty perplexed when Ellie asked Joel "You ever play this one?" pointing to the old Mortal Combat arcade. It was so unusual for me so I even switched the subtitles on and double-checked it, but it was just as I heard. A Present Simple form instead of "Have you ever played this one?"

To be honest I've never heard of such a substitution. I found a couple of threads regarding this matter, but it didn't seem that this case fell under explanations in previous questions.

Is this something that is common in spoken language?

Comment: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- *You ever **play** this one?*

isn't short for

- ***Have** you ever **played** this one?*

because the verb form used is *play*, the infinitive, not *played*, the past participle, which comes after *have* in the perfect. Infinitives like *play* come after modals and *do*, so *You ever play this one?* is short for

- ***Did** you ever **play** this one?*

according to the very common rule of [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), which removes **predictable** auxiliaries, prepositions, articles, dummies, possessives, pronouns, and conditional *if* from the beginning of a sentence, going on with the deletions until unpredictable information is encountered.

Here's some more examples:

- *Wife's on the phone, Bill.*
- *Never expected that.* (= ***I** never expected it*)
- *Never expected that, did you?* (= ***You** never expected it*)
- *Never expected that, did she?* (= ***She** never expected it*)
- *Ever get to Bellingham, look me up.* (= ***If you** ever...*)

It's surprising you haven't heard this before. But most people just stick in the missing words and never notice they're missing.

Comment: I *believe* that this is one of the cases  where American English allows the simple past but British English prefers the present perfect (for "present-relevant" information). If the asker speaks BrE that might explain their confusion.

Comment: Is "You ever play this one?" short for "Did you ever play this one?" ? Possibly, but *not necessarily*. "You ever play this one?" could also be short for "Do you ever play this one?"

Comment: That totally makes sense now, thank you. For some reason, my mind was fixated on the idea that it should have been the Present Perfect, so I didn't think that it could be the Past Simple.

Comment: Various intermediate forms also occur in speech. "Didya ever play this one?" makes a link quite clearly (probably more like "didyerever" with an audible "r" for me, coming from London), while "D'you..." could be "do you..." or "did you..." depending on context.

Comment: The "have you ever..." form is also a feasible expansion of the short form, I think it depends on context. "Did you ever play this one?" seems like an option if the game is no longer available for some reason, while "Have you ever played this one?" works if it is still available.

Comment: Why do you think it is short for _did_ not _do_ ?

Comment: In context, _You ever play this one?_ can refer to either _do_ or _did_. In context, the choice would be either obvious or irrelevant -- depending, for instance, on whether it was delivered as a simple request for information, or a challenge by the speaker to beat them at the game. If it weren't obvious, it wouldn't be deleted; whenever words are deleted, information is lost, and it's usually redundant information, which we expect addressees to pick up from context. If they don't, we may judge them to be rather slow on the uptake; there's more than one reason for deletion rules.